# Deploying React/Redux App on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, solidity, truffle

I want to deploy a [react app](https://github.com/truffle-box/react-auth-box) on Heroku.

I run `npm run build` which creates a productionized version into the build_webpack folder. I do a `git add .` on this folder and try to submit but Heroku doesn't recognize the buildpack.

> remote: Building source: remote: remote: -----> App not compatible
>   with buildpack: https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi
>   remote:        More info:
>   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
>   remote: remote:  !     Push failed remote: Verifying deploy...

Answer (score -1):

if you want to deploy your code to heroku , you should use this command 
first you need a free heroku account 
next you should install heroku on your machine 
and after that login using this command

`heroku login`

after you loged in , cd to your project dir and enter this command

`heroku create $APP_NAME $BRANCH:MASTER --buildpack mars/create-react-app`

if you are on branch master you don't have to enter $BRANCH: